# How to get PDO up and running?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm kind of a newbie PHP programmer and never heard about PDO until a few days ago. Up until now I have just used the default MySQL functions in PHP for my website, but from what I've been reading it seems like I really should switch to PDO.

I recompiled Apache, enabling PDO, but when I try to connect with the following code:

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error!: could not find driver
```

I ran phpinfo() and found the following relevant to PDO:

> './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-phar' '--enable-bcmath'
>   '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
>   '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring'
>   '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local'
>   '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/'
>   '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext'
>   '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr'
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos'
>   '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/'
>   '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
>   '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr'
>   '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre'
>   '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-png-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib'
>   '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'

```
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     sqlite, sqlite2

pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1
```

How do I get PDO working?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you enabled the PDO extension in php.ini?

Comment: Some tips: `PDO drivers     sqlite, sqlite2`, `new PDO('mysql'...` and `Error!: could not find driver`

Comment: I would read that as you only have the sqlite, and sqlite2 drivers for PDO, hence its complaining not that it cant do PDO, but it cant do mysql

Comment: Please refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also add the pdo-mysql extension:

```
--with-pdo-mysql=shared
```

Some extra info:

Also always add the encoding of the database:

```
$dbh= new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
```

Always disable emulated prepared statements (for mysql)

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Since you are just starting with PDO I also suggest this tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: You're welcome. I'm always more than happy to move people away from the ancient mysql_ functions :)